# ‘pile of paper’ look for mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I’m trying to get and `mdframed` environment to look like a messy pile of paper.

I’ve figured out how to use tikz `preactions` to get the kind of look that I’m after (see code below).

[image: messy pile of paper]

I was hoping to get the same look by passing a `tikzsetting` to `mdframed`, but it doesn’t seem to do a thing. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
[preaction={draw=black, fill=white, transform canvas={rotate=1, xshift=2mm, yshift=-2mm}}]
[preaction={draw=black, fill=white, transform canvas={rotate=-1, xshift=.5mm, yshift=-1mm}}]
[fill=white](0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{mdframed}[tikzsetting={preaction={draw=black, fill=white, transform canvas={rotate=1, xshift=2mm, yshift=-2mm}},
                              preaction={draw=black, fill=white, transform canvas={rotate=-1, xshift=.5mm, yshift=-1mm}},
                              draw=black, fill=white}]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a `mdframed`, but a `tcolorbox` solution, by applying a `frame code pre` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,enhanced,sharp corners,
  frame code pre={%
      \draw[fill=white,transform canvas={rotate=1,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm}] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
      \draw[fill=white,transform canvas={rotate=-1,xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm}] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
    }]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{pileofpaper}[1][]{%
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  enhanced,sharp corners,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  frame code pre={%
    \foreach \al/ \x / \y in {1/-1mm/-2mm,-1/-2mm/3mm,-2/2mm/-1mm,3/-2mm/-2mm} {
      \draw[draw=tcbcol@frame,line width=0.2*\kvtcb@left@rule,
      fill=tcbcol@back,
      transform canvas={rotate=\al,xshift=\x,yshift=\y}
      ] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
    }
  },
  #1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pileofpaper}[colback=white!95!gray,colframe=blue]
  \blindtext
\end{pileofpaper}
\end{document}
```

[image]